# Save duplicates by id

Tags: stata

I have two variables in Stata, `id` and `price`:

```
id price
1  4321
1  7634
1  7974
1  7634
1  3244
2  5943
2  3294
2  5645
2  3564
2  4321
2  4567
2  4567
2  4567
2  4567
3  5652
3  9586
3  5844
3  8684
3  2456
4  7634
```

Usually I can use the `duplicates` command to get the duplicate observations of a variable.

However, how can I create a new variable that will save the duplicates
of `price` for each `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Super late, but just so there is an answer:

```
duplicates tag id, gen(dup)
bysort id: gen n = _n
reshape wide price, i(id) j(n)
```

Comment: It's hard to know whether this is what the OP wanted -- note that they asked for _a new variable_ [twice, and singular] and this creates several. But it may be what someone wants. Also, there is an answer already! (+1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that I can see for `duplicates` to work with `by:`. `duplicates` whatever `price id` is the general recipe with your example, to examine duplicates jointly for two variables.  Consider

```
clear 
input id price
1  4321
1  7634
1  7974
1  7634
1  3244
2  5943
2  3294
2  5645
2  3564
2  4321
2  4567
2  4567
2  4567
2  4567
3  5652
3  9586
3  5844
3  8684
3  2456
4  7634
end 

. duplicates example id price 

Duplicates in terms of id price

  +------------------------------------+
  | group:   #   e.g. obs   id   price |
  |------------------------------------|
  |      1   2          2    1    7634 |
  |      2   4         11    2    4567 |
  +------------------------------------+

. duplicates tag id price, gen(tag) 

Duplicates in terms of id price

. list id price if tag , sepby(id) 

     +------------+
     | id   price |
     |------------|
  2. |  1    7634 |
  4. |  1    7634 |
     |------------|
 11. |  2    4567 |
 12. |  2    4567 |
 13. |  2    4567 |
 14. |  2    4567 |
     +------------+
```

Beyond that, I am not clear exactly what output or data result you wish to see.

EDIT In response to comment, here are two more direct approaches. `duplicates` is based on the idea that duplicates are mostly unwanted; you seem to have the opposite point of view, in which case `duplicates` is oblique to your wants.

```
* approach 1 
bysort price id : gen wanted = _n == 1 & _N > 1 

list if wanted 

     +---------------------+
     | id   price   wanted |
     |---------------------|
  7. |  2    4567        1 |
 15. |  1    7634        1 |
     +---------------------+

* approach 2 
drop wanted 

bysort price id : keep if _n == 1 & _N > 1 

list 

     +------------+
     | id   price |
     |------------|
  1. |  2    4567 |
  2. |  1    7634 |
     +------------+
```

Naturally if you want to duplicate data yet further (why?) then after approach 1

```
gen duplicated_price = price if wanted
```

gives you one copy of each of the duplicated values in a new variable. This is a slightly simpler equivalent of @Pearly Spencer's approach.

```
bysort price id : gen duplicated_price = price if _n == 1 & _N > 1
```

does it in one line.

Comment: Thanks but I want to save a unique copy of each duplicate for each id in a new variable not list them.